# How to change the starting point on a path when using a brush to stroke?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, brush

I'm using a brush to stroke a path in different frames and layers to get a sparkle animation. The special brush settings are 1000% spacing and 50% size jitter.

The problem is that the brush always starts at the same place/point, so there is a brush object that remains intact in the animation (pointed with the red arrows at the image below).

Is there a way to solve this? Changing some brush parameters or something else? This image is an example with a simple path, in the real illustration the path is an irregular shape, so flipping the path is not an option. The animation is a small part of an action, the solution must be just using Photoshop (no external applications or scripts).

[image: sparkle]

Comment: Did you try to rotate the path? Steps of 90 degrees.

Comment: It's an irregular path, not symmetrical. Imagine a lower case "g".

Comment: What if if make it regular?

Comment: The animation is over a two-word text with a texture, impossible to get a regular shape. As I describe in the question, the sample image is a simple example to show how the brush works on the same path.

Comment: Try to make a selection using the path and make a new path using this new selection. I did not try but it can change the initial anchor point.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work, Photoshop always takes the same starting point to make the path. When not finding a solution with the path, I am trying other alternatives.

Comment: @Danielillo kind of self promotion eh? :P

Comment: Self promotion? It's an old question, I don't remember how I solve the action, but sure with a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

This resembles a recent case. I answer the same. Split the path somewhere to make it an open path. Rejoin the ends. The new starting point is now the splitting point.

I havent tools to do it in Photoshop (legacy stuff), but I copied my path to Illustrator, where I splitted it with the scissors and joined the shape with Ctrl+J. After copying and pasting the path back to Photoshop I stroked it again. The result: The starting point had changed.

In the following image the work path has got a scattered brush stroke. The path is splitted+rejoined in Illustrator and pasted back to PS. It has got the same stroke:

[image]

Comment: The animation is a small part of a fairly complex action and is to be used by other users, so there can not be an external application to Photoshop.

Comment: @Danielillo sorry, I uderstood the case totally wrongly. Maybe you can change "prefer" to "accept only"